Opening a .zip object, from a APS bucket, in Desing Automation
I'm having some issues trying to do some funny stuff with Design Automation.
Imagine I have a bucket, in it there is a .zip with one, or several .rvt files.
What I'm trying to do is, Use Design Automation on this .zip file,iterate trhough the .rvt files, do something and retur the zip file back.
But here is the problem: everytime I execute the workitem, it throw's?

Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: The document can not be opened.

So I'm failing in even opening the .zip file? Or some configuration in my activity or workitem arguments. Where am I wrong?
Here's the commandLine's I've tried:
commandLine = "$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[{0}].path)\""

commandLine = "$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[DA_UpdateParameters].path)\""

So here is my activity:
{
  "parameters": {
    "inputFile": {
      "verb": "get",
      "description": "Input .zip file containing .rvt files",
      "localName": "input.zip",
      "required": true,
      "zip": true
    },
    "inputJson": {
      "verb": "get",
      "description": "Input json",
      "localName": "params.json",
      "required": true
    },
    "outputFile": {
      "verb": "put",
      "description": "Output .zip file with modified .rvt files",
      "localName": "output.zip",
      "required": true,
      "zip": true,
    }
  }
}

And the worktitem arguments
"BoundArguments": {
  "inputFile": {
    "localName": "input.zip",
    "url": $"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{bucketKey}/objects/{objectKey}",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:qOVja1kpv9L9ytsDkkZA24iYBYY="
    },
    "verb": "get"
  },
  "inputJson": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "data:application/json, {'elementsToChange':[{'PointId':'4','NewLocation':    {'dx':'','dy':''}}]}",
    "verb": "get"
  },
  "outputFile": {
    "localName": "OutputFile.zip",
    "url": $"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{bucketKey}/objects/output/{outputFileName},
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:qOVja1kpv9L9ytsDkkZA24iYBYY="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}


The Activity parameters and Work Item arguments don't even match up: e.g. inputZip vs inputFile. 
Also, if you are working with a zip file and try to pass that as an input in the commandLine to open a file from inside it, you'd also need to provide pathInZip
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/localname-pathinzip-zip


Yeah, that was a error of mine when posting this question, sorry for that.
But in both activity and workitems arguments they have th same name:  inputFile, inputJson and outputFile.
Can it be becausa the real objectKey is not in the 'localName' of the workitem argument?

No, as I said (and pointed out in the blog post I referenced) you need to provide pathInZip

Sorry for that. Now I understood what you've said and thank you very much for this clarification! I've made it, but now with some other message as Exception: Revit input file not found: T:\Aces\Jobs\7b56428das03184041231231206227c5\inputFile{my-object-key}

Also... i've noticed in the log, that when DA makes the download, it names my object some other name, kind of random name like "zip_172.zip".
Did I screw up the configs in the commandLIne?

Maybe DA4R ignores localName in case of pathInZip. You should double-check that the relative path you provide for pathInZip is correct - e.g. if you zipped a folder that contains the files (instead of zipping the files directly) then add that to the path: folder/myfile.rvt
